# If I name a table sizes will it conflict with the method sizes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rails-activerecord

I was working on a project where I named a table sizes and I was having a lot of difficulty and errors, though I can't remember the specific errors I was getting last week.

I went back a few migrations to try to improve my project with some of the things I've learned without having to deal with some of my mistakes when it suddenly occurred to me that part one of my issues may have been a conflict between the table name and the size method.

Has anyone else run into an issue like this? Is this a reasonable assumption? If it is, do you have a better word for sizes that won't conflict with a method?

Comment: how about `variants`?

Comment: `Size` is a perfectly valid model name in Rails and causes no conflicts.

Comment: I went with variants to have no doubt and because I hadn't heard from @Iceman